# How to implement a Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm new to Android Studio, and I am going through the tutorials on the website.

It shows buttons in the toolbar like, 'hide constraints' 'default margins', and 'autoconnect'. But I can't find these buttons in my Android Studio.

Can anyone help me find them and make them visible in the Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Those are visible when you use a ConstrainedLayout in your Layout's xml file.